# How can I display a user avatar in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users, media

I'd like to know how to display a user avatar in Drupal 7. I want to display the avatar in full size, and as thumbnail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code used from [user_user_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_user_view/7) is the following one:

```
$account->content['user_picture'] = array(
  '#markup' => theme('user_picture', array('account' => $account)), 
  '#weight' => -10,
);
```

For example, if you want to output the HTML code to show the picture associated with the currently logged-in user in a form, you could use code similar to the following one:

```
$form['user_picture'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'user_picture',
  '#account' => $GLOBALS['user'], 
);
```

This is similar to the following code used in node_admin_nodes(), which uses a different theme function.

```
$form['nodes'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table', 
  '#header' => $header, 
  '#rows' => $options, 
  '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
);
```

The content of "#header," "#rows," and "#empty" are used to populate the content of the `$variables` array that is passed to the theme function ("#header" becomes "header," etc).

`theme('user_picture')` works even when the Image module (the one that defines `theme_image_style()`) is not enabled; in that case, it uses `theme_image()` instead. When the Image module is enabled, it uses the default style as contained in the Drupal variable "user_picture_style." In both the cases, the user image is a link to the user profile.

As the theme function is using a template ([user-picture.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user-picture.tpl.php/7)), the relevant code is in [template_preprocess_user_picture()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/template_preprocess_user_picture/7); if you look at the code for [theme_user_picture()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--theme.php/function/theme_user_picture/7), you would see there is no code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to change the size of the avatar: thumbnail, medium, large? I use this code: `global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
$account->content['user_picture'] = array(
  '#markup' => theme('user_picture', array('account' => $account)), 
  '#weight' => -10,
);
print ($account->content['user_picture']['#markup']);` And I also don't understand why `'#weight' => -10` is used here. I know what it means in form api.

Comment: "#weight" is used for every form field to order them; in this case −10 would put the user image on top of the form. For the other question, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A user's profile picture is available on the loaded user object. You can use [image_style](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) theme function to render an image in the size of your choosing.

Comment: where can i read how to use this function?